# Xubuntu unmet dependencies when try to install texlive-latex-base

Tags: package-management, texlive

Sure that it is a duplicate question of this list:

[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

[How to run 'apt-get install' to install all dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214746/how-to-run-apt-get-install-to-install-all-dependencies)

[apt-get does not install dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313696/apt-get-does-not-install-dependencies)

[What does "packages have unmet dependecies" mean and what can I do about it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610909/what-does-packages-have-unmet-dependecies-mean-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

[Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

and many other, but, none works for me,

I have xubuntu Xenial 16.04

naively try to install texlive-latex-base so:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 texlive-latex-base : Depends: texlive-base (>= 2015) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: texlive-latex-base-doc but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If the program can show the dependencies, so why it can not resolve?

Making some search: "apt install dependencies"

Then try:

```
sudo apt -f install texlive-latex-base
sudo apt-get -f install  texlive-latex-base
```

Also

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get build-dep build-essential
```

And get the same message.

### Also try this sequence of commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -f -> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 258 not upgraded.
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -f
     The following packages will be upgraded:
     a lot of package but not texlive
     I respond with Yes
     and a lot of packages was dowloaded
```

And try again:

```
   sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base
   and get the same message:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
        bla bla
        E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

Then install Aptitude:

```
sudo aptitude -f install texlive-latex-base
```

respond with Y
show

```
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

### nothing happend

Then install Synaptic,when mark to install is show with red sign "!" that mean Broken status,
search how to fix it, 
go Status, Broken dependencies, try to Mark for complete removal but it is disable.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please include the complete output of `apt policy texlive-base`

Comment: `apt policy texlive-base
texlive-base:
      Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1
  Version table:   
     2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
     2015.20160320-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
`

Comment: What you did wrong (258 packages to be upgraded ago) is to install something from a non-Ubuntu source. If you need interactive help to locate what you did, move your question over to ubuntuforumsorg. If you know what you did, then uninstall all the packages from that lousy source, and then disable that source.